# When Node CSR(kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving) coming?

Tags: ansible

Provision the kubernetes cluster with Ansible like [this](https://github.com/flavono123/kubernetes-the-hard-way/tree/main/provisioning).

I added [codes](https://github.com/flavono123/kubernetes-the-hard-way/commit/b77c5bc23ee9694996ceaad9a6c38f708397e479) for [enabling signed kubelet serving certificates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#kubelet-serving-certs)(for using [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server)).

[The commented codes from above](https://github.com/flavono123/kubernetes-the-hard-way/commit/b77c5bc23ee9694996ceaad9a6c38f708397e479#diff-aec024ca6f7354bcab1390bc1902e426ee2decdefdd7870fb79aa542e6d83fc8R114-R131) are not working since the expected CSRs, from each node and signer is the `kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving`, are arrived **only after Ansible playbook is over**.

1. I tried the pause between the restarting kubelets and list CSRs, but it didn't working:

```bash
# In controlplane
$ k get csr --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp
NAME        AGE   SIGNERNAME                                    REQUESTOR                      REQUESTEDDURATION   CONDITION
csr-xkfrl   77s   kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client-kubelet   system:node:cluster1-master1   <none>              Approved,Issued
csr-4j72q   58s   kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client-kubelet   system:bootstrap:asn18v        <none>              Approved,Issued
csr-n84d7   58s   kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client-kubelet   system:bootstrap:auwd4d        <none>              Approved,Issued
csr-rrt46   57s   kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client-kubelet   system:bootstrap:m9ozid        <none>              Approved,Issued
csr-j54mz   40s   kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving                 system:node:cluster1-worker2   <none>              Pending          <- Expected CSR created after playbook over
csr-tc2fr   40s   kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving                 system:node:cluster1-worker1   <none>              Pending
csr-xfsj5   40s   kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving                 system:node:cluster1-master1   <none>              Pending
csr-8dhkd   40s   kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving                 system:node:cluster1-worker3   <none>              Pending

# The latency between the bootstrap join and the exepected CSRs creation is about 18s(58 - 40)

# With pause 90s after notify restart kubelet
$ k get csr --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp
NAME        AGE     SIGNERNAME                                    REQUESTOR                      REQUESTEDDURATION   CONDITION
csr-dppzq   3m5s    kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client-kubelet   system:node:cluster1-master1   <none>              Approved,Issued
csr-tckhh   2m46s   kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client-kubelet   system:bootstrap:5rgz1f        <none>              Approved,Issued
csr-fqbk6   2m46s   kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client-kubelet   system:bootstrap:u90j5e        <none>              Approved,Issued
csr-gdg6l   2m46s   kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client-kubelet   system:bootstrap:nnzo29        <none>              Approved,Issued
csr-j2bll   58s     kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving                 system:node:cluster1-worker1   <none>              Pending          <- Expected CSR 
csr-s8kqf   58s     kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving                 system:node:cluster1-master1   <none>              Pending
csr-9zqfn   58s     kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving                 system:node:cluster1-worker3   <none>              Pending
csr-zp5qt   58s     kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving                 system:node:cluster1-worker2   <none>              Pending

# It shows the latency is increased by paused seconds 90s (108s = 166 - 58)
```

2. There is no way to wait the filtered objects, for now the CSRs whose signer is `kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving`(The option [field_selectors](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_info_module.html#parameter-field_selectors) works for filtering from the result list).

---

Questions:

- When the CSRs are created, the signer is `kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving` and the requestor is `system:node:<node>`?
- It delayed for Ansible? (It seems so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about Ansible.

[Notify handlers run at the end of playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#controlling-when-handlers-run).

So, run it immediately, with some graceful period, makes the problem solved([my commit](https://github.com/flavono123/kubernetes-the-hard-way/commit/f51299712f0712ed58ea6c26492ccc7e57f27175)):

```yaml
- name: Flush handlers for restarting kubelets
  meta: flush_handlers

- name: Wait graceful period for restarting kubelets and creating CSRs
  pause:
    seconds: 30
```